# AWS ECS Cluster not utilizing resources efficiently due to suboptimal task distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have set up an AWS ECS Cluster with an ECS Service using binpack task placement and an ASG (Auto Scaling Group) with managed scaling and no manage instance protection. However, I have noticed that sometimes the service tasks are distributed between two instances, even when they can both be run on a single instance. This suboptimal distribution leads to underutilization of resources.

Here is an example of the suboptimal task distribution:

[Two task distributed between two instances when they can be run on one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwJMP.png)

Since I am using Managed Scaling with a target capacity of 100% and considering how the `CapacityProviderReservation` is calculated, the ASG doesn't scale down as desired. Consequently, I am unable to optimize resource allocation and reduce costs effectively.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this issue. Specifically, I would like to know how to configure my AWS ECS Cluster and associated services to ensure that the tasks are distributed efficiently and that the ASG scales down appropriately when resources are not fully utilized.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!